# Type hinting for multiple return values on caller side

Tags: python, type-hinting

A lot of questions discuss the syntax used when returning multiple values from a function, i.e.

```
def bar(a:int,b:int) -> Tuple(int,int):
    return a//b, a%b
```

But it seems no one has answered the question of how to specify the types on the caller side i.e

```
def foo(a:int, b:int) -> None:
    quotient, remainder: **(HOW TO TYPE HINT THIS)** = bar(a,b)
    print(quotient, remainder)
```

Does anybody know how to do this? I looked at the PEP guidelines but they didn't help much. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing what the issue is but the hints for calling `bar` are already in your code.

Comment: Why would you want to type-hint on the caller side? The return value of the function is already hinted in its definition.

Comment: In case foo in another package/module/script from bar or in some way the return value type is hard to access.